# Editable cell in datatable LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, css, lightning-datatable, style

I am trying to create datatable with cells that will be editable only if a condition was true. I was looking for a solution with the CellAtributtes. `cellAttributes: { class: {fieldName : "disable" } }` with a custom CSS style but the cell don't get the custom styles.

Comment: Hi Juan, Welcome to SFSE! Please take a tour on [ask] and edit your question to mention the things you have tried so far and exactly what is not working for you.

Comment: Juan, you can also look up existing questions by tag: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightning-datatable?sort=frequent